# Selenium WebDriverWait can't wait for execute_script twice?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried to get the shadowRoot element in the page through execute_script(), I didn't want to use time.sleep(), so I chose WebDriverWait. When I called WebDriverWait.until() for the first time, it seemed to really wait; when I called WebDriverWait.until() for the second time, it didn’t seem to wait, and Chrome exited after calling maximize_window(). Finally, the following error is output.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as wait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


with webdriver.Chrome() as browser:
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 30, 1)
    
    browser.get("https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/search")

    element = wait.until(
        lambda browser: browser.execute_script("""return document.querySelector('home-view').shadowRoot.querySelector('vt-ui-search-bar').shadowRoot.querySelector('vt-ui-text-input')""")
    )

    if element:
        element.send_keys('5f580868011b6c0deb8bde8355630019')
        element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    
        browser.maximize_window()

        #Must be using time.sleep() ???
        
        result = wait.until(
            lambda browser: browser.execute_script("""return document.querySelector('file-view').shadowRoot.querySelector('vt-ui-file-card').shadowRoot.querySelector('vt-ui-generic-card').children[1].textContent.trim()""")
        )

        if result:
            print(result)
```

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:12247/devtools/browser/11eba3c5-3044-4835-94a9-8db6b56687f4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\source\VsCode\py\jupyter\test15.py", line 22, in <module>
    result = wait.until(
  File "D:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 78, in until
    value = method(self._driver)
  File "d:\source\VsCode\py\jupyter\test15.py", line 23, in <lambda>
    lambda browser: browser.execute_script("""return document.querySelector('file-view').shadowRoot.querySelector('vt-ui-file-card').shadowRoot.querySelector('vt-ui-generic-card').children[1].textContent.trim()""")
  File "D:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 878, in execute_script
    return self.execute(command, {
  File "D:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 424, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'shadowRoot')
  (Session info: chrome=97.0.4692.71)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        Ordinal0 [0x008A6903+2517251]
        Ordinal0 [0x0083F8E1+2095329]
        Ordinal0 [0x00742848+1058888]
        Ordinal0 [0x00744F44+1068868]
        Ordinal0 [0x00744E0E+1068558]
        Ordinal0 [0x007456BA+1070778]
        Ordinal0 [0x007964F9+1402105]
        Ordinal0 [0x007864D3+1336531]
        Ordinal0 [0x00795BBF+1399743]
        Ordinal0 [0x0078639B+1336219]
        Ordinal0 [0x007627A7+1189799]
        Ordinal0 [0x00763609+1193481]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00A35904+1577972]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00AE0B97+2279047]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00936D09+534521]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00935DB9+530601]
        Ordinal0 [0x00844FF9+2117625]
        Ordinal0 [0x008498A8+2136232]
        Ordinal0 [0x008499E2+2136546]
        Ordinal0 [0x00853541+2176321]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x7683FA29+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x76FB7A9E+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x76FB7A6E+238]
```

Answer (score 1):

By default `until` handles only `TimeoutException`, but you are getting `JavascriptException` on one of the attempts to get an attribute from `shadowRoot` that is not yet present and therefore is `null`. `Until` can handle `null`/`None` result, but only on the returned value, not while executing the condition method.

One solution (and the simpler) is adding `JavascriptException` to the `ignored_exceptions` list when creating the `WebDriverWait` instance

```
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 30, 1, ignored_exceptions=JavascriptException)
```

Another solution will be to split the script to parts and check for the availability of `shadowRoot` each time

```
result = wait.until(
    lambda browser: browser.execute_script(
        """
        value = document.querySelector('file-view').shadowRoot.querySelector('vt-ui-file-card');
        if (value) {
            value = value.shadowRoot.querySelector('vt-ui-generic-card');
            if (value) {
                value = value.children[1].textContent.trim();
            }
        }
        return value;""")
)
```

Comment: I ran this code and it seems to do the job. OP will have to make changes into `querySelector` to get the desired output, right now the output is `db4ac82d2c8db0dbc73e772b0b02c9e3917bbf13363bc37a0001dd2851304a4a  pythompy2     1.17 MB  Size   2019-12-09 09:51:35 UTC`

Comment: Due to network reasons, both requests and responses are relatively slow. Should I wait for a while before calling execute_script() a second time? If I use time.sleep() to wait for the display, does wait.until() still make sense?

Comment: @fs you can always increase the time defined in `WebDriverWait`